# How to observe adViewWillLeaveApplication Admob

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I am putting ads into my app, but when I click on the banner, it seems like there is a delay when calling my observer method to stop all timers, and are only stopped when the app leaves, not when the ad is clicked, which messes things up a little. so I implemented this method into my App delegate:

```
func adViewWillLeaveApplication(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewWillLeaveApplication")
}
```

Now in the scene where I want to detect when an ad is clicked has this code:

```
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pauseTimers), name: /* what goes here? */, object: nil)
```

I am unsure of what to put within the comments. I cannot find adViewWillLeaveApplication (and I have imported GoogleMobileAds).

What do I need to put instead?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get it right. Do you want to receive a notification when the `adViewWillLeaveApplication` delegate method is called? In that case the name of the NSNotification goes in the "name" argument.

Eg. you do a `NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "adViewWillLeaveApplicationNotification"), object: nil, userInfo: nil) ` in the delegate method and just put `NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "adViewWillLeaveApplicationNotification")` there as the argument.

Comment: Ok I have done that put I have tested it and doesn't seem to be calling the selector...